# How to run sudo in terraform "local-exec" block

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform

I have an issue where adding sudo in local exec keep running.

So in short without the local-exec block. I'm able to create and access my EC2 instance. using ssh -vi path/to/key.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

But now as soon as I add below block; and run `apply` it keeps showing "still creating" after the password prompt.

```
 provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOH
      sudo yum -y update
      sudo yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip
    EOH
  }
```

So, my question is which user is sudo user here? is it ec2-user or the user which I created initially to setup my AWS (that includes only access key id and secret access key)?

How can I set it up, is there any documentation to refer?

below is my main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
  version = "~> 1.2.0"
}

resource "aws_instance" "hello-world" {
  ami = "ami-ef92b08a"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOH
      sudo yum -y update
      sudo yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip
    EOH
  }

  tags {
    Name = "my-aws-terraform-hello-world"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "allow-tcp" {
  name = "my-aws-terraform-hello-world"
  ingress {
    from_port = 8080
    to_port = 8080
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Local-exec runs locally ie on your machine, not the instance you just created. Use remote-exec instead to connect to your EC2 instance (or better yet use user data or even better yet bake as much as possible into an AMI and just deploy that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Commands inside `local-exec` runs locally on your machine after the instance is created. Use `remote-exec` as below to run your commands on EC2 Instance.**

```
 connection {
    type     = "ssh"
    user     = "ec2-user"
    host = "${self.private_ip}"
    private_key  = "${file("/path/to/your/pemfile")}"
    agent = true
  }
```

then you can specify remote-exec block

```
 provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo yum -y update",
      "sudo yum install -y python36 python36-libs python36-devel python36-pip",
    ]
  }
```

**Multiple remote provisioners can use same connection block if its in outside block.**

Comment: thanks. for some reason, I have the same problem in the remote-exec block as well. from my local machine, I can see it reached AWS EC2 public IP but can't execute the commands. Do you have any idea why so? it's trying to keep looping in connection block? inline = [
      "sudo yum -y update",
      "sudo yum install -y python36 python36-libs python36-devel python36-pip",
    ] and connection { type = "ssh"
      user = "ec2-user"
      password = ""
      private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/my-key-pair.pem")}"
      host = "${self.private_ip}"
      timeout = "2m"
      agent = false
    }

Comment: can you show the log or error msg? and are you able ssh into ec2? ssh -i /path/to/pemfile user@ip_address.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an EC2 instance, I would encourage you to use USER_DATA, this will run as part of the image creation. AWS docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

Here is the the [user_data](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#user_data) property for Terraform.

Here is how you would achieve what you are doing and since USER_DATA runs as root you don't need sudo.

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami = "hello-world"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  user_data = <<-EOF
                #!/bin/bash
                yum -y update
                yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip
              EOF
  tags {
    Name = "my-aws-terraform-hello-world"
  }
}
```